# Android Emulator Virtualization

Tags: android, graphics, android-studio, virtualization

I am trying to write android apps but found out that my computer does not support virtualization technology which is required for the emulator. Is there any possible way to test apps without an emulator or a way to get an emulator which does not require virtualization?

Answer (score 0):

Try Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/#!/ (free for personal usage)

It's much faster than the android emulator

Comment: but doesn't genymotion also require virtualization technology, which my computer doesn't support?

Comment: Yes It uses VirtualBox :/ sorry. The virtualization is just disable or you processor and your motherboard doesn't support it at all ?

Comment: my motherboard doesn't support it at all =/

Comment: Did you try that https://www.manymo.com/. Everything seems to be launch from the browser so I don't thing you need to support virtualization on your computer.